# Adding event listener to checkbox w/out using html onchange

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I want to add an event listener to an id which then alters some css. But without using html onchange, I have this (code below) so far. I'm almost certain im using addEventListener wrong.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById('no_photo');
    alert('win loaded');
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', function() {
      alert('event triggered');
      var photo = document.getElementById('photo_upload');
      if(photo.style.display != 'none') {
        photo.style.display = 'none';
      } 
      else if(photo.style.display == 'none') {
        photo.style.display = 'block';
      };
    });
  }
```

Comment: You need to specify `click` in quotes... `checkbox.addEventListener("change",` Check your console for errors

Comment: fixed by using 'change' not click thanks for the help guys

Comment: Cool, it should also work with 'click' though: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nJAvc/)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
checkbox.addEventListener(click, ...
```

instead of

```
checkbox.addEventListener('click', ...
```

Use your browser console to detect this kind of syntax errors.

You can open the console in most browsers by typing CTRL-SHIFT-i

Comment: Thanks, changing that still doesnt trigger the event :/